# Show a set is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and let $K=\{x \in G: x^2 \in H\}$. Prove that $K$ is a
subgroup of $G$.

---

Suppose $xy \in G.$ Since $H \subseteq G, xy \in H.$ Since $H$ is closed under multiplication, $(xy)^2 \in H.$ So, $xy \in K.$

The same argument is valid for $x^{-1}$?

$H$ is a group, so $ e \in H.$ Since $e^2 = e, e^2 \in H$. So, $e \in K.$

Please, check my work.

Comment: Is $G$ an abelian group?

Comment: @ Matt Samuel, yes $G$ is abelian.

Comment: The line "Suppose $xy \in G.$ Since $H \subseteq G, xy \in H$" is not true. You need to start from $x, y \in K$ and have to show that $xy \in K.$ Also I think commutativity is required.

Comment: @ Krish, Suppose $x, y \in K.$ Then $x, y \in G.$ Since $G$ is a group, $xy \in G \ldots$ Like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've shown that $e\in K$, but you haven't correctly shown that $K$ is closed under multiplication. To show that $K$ is closed under multiplication, let $x,y\in K$. Then since $(xy)^2 = x^2 y^2$ and $x^2, y^2\in H$, closure under multiplication in $H$ implies $(xy)^2\in H$. Hence $xy\in K$.

For closure under inverses, note that for any $x\in K$, $(x^{-1})^2 = (x^2)^{-1} \in H$ since $x^2 \in H$ and $H$ is closed under inverses. Therefore $x^{-1}\in K$.

Comment: @ kobe, are $x^2, y^2 \in H$ because $H$ is closed under multiplication?

Comment: @Max no, it's because $x,y\in K$.

Comment: @ kobe, that's by definition of $K$. Ok. If we let $x \in K$, then by definition of $K$, $x^2 \in H.$ I see. Since $H$ is closed under inverses, $(x^2)^{-1} \in H.$ That means $(x^{-1})^2 \in H.$ By definition of K, then, $x^{-1} \in K.$ Is that correct?

Comment: @Max correct! :-)